# How to add an platform Messenger Facebook dynamic

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, messenger

i have an Facebook Messenger application. I want to have an button on my app that user Connect Chatbot to your Page. I cannot find how to do this on Facebook docs but i know that Chatfuel do this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use Facebook Login and OAuth protocol. Through login you will get back an OAuth token which allows you to connect an app to one of the page of a user. You can find all relevant information there : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/